# Is NEOS solver in Pyomo package updated?

Tags: pyomo, neos-server

As per the link from NEOS twitter page, they say an Email address needs to be added before submitting the job. Is the pyomo for NEOS solver updated accordingly? Please find the links below for more info:

https://twitter.com/NeosOpt/status/1336360894884966401

https://neos-guide.org/content/FAQ#email - Refer to 10th question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed now. Pull the repo from the link provided below and we have to add Email ID into path variable and then run the code. Fix is in the below link:

Fix link:
https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/1784

Repo link:
https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/tree/master/pyomo/neos

Comment: I saw the repo, what do you mean by adding Email ID into the path variable?

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/1817 for more info on how to add Email.